# Moving element with JavaScript in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm coding a web application where the user can pan a map by dragging an image inside a div element with the mouse. Unfortunately, I need it to be cross-browser, to support IE 6-9, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. And I'm trapped inside a framework that poses limitations on what I can do with javascript, so the simpler the better. The code below (amazingly) worked, until I added "!DOCTYPE html". What's the error? How would you debug this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>
<style>
p{ width: 400px; background-color: gold;}
#caption {text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}
div div {
width:400px; height: 140px; 
border: 1px solid green;
background-color: lightgreen;
display: block;
position: relative;
}
div div:hover {border-color: red;}
div > .img {
  width: 200px; height: 100px; top: 10px; left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://boallen.com/assets/images/randbitmap_true.png');
}
div > .img:hover {cursor: pointer; background-color: lightgray;}
</style>

<div>
<div>p
  <span class="img" id="friend">bad ie</span>
</div>
<div id="thediv">Mouse in here and click<br></div>
</div>

<script>
var el   = document.getElementById("thediv");
var img = document.getElementById('friend');

img.onmousedown = function (event) {
  img.moving=true;
  img.mouseX=(window.event ? window.event.x: event.clientX) - img.offsetLeft;
  img.mouseY=(window.event ? window.event.y: event.clientY) - img.offsetTop;
  el.innerHTML += 'Mouse DOWN ';
}
img.onmousemove = function (event) {
  if(!img.moving) return;
  img.style.left=(window.event ? window.event.x: event.clientX) - img.mouseX;
  img.style.top=(window.event ? window.event.y: event.clientY) - img.mouseY;
  stat.innerHTML += "M-M ";
}
img.onmouseup = function (event) {
  this.moving = false;
  el.innerHTML += 'Mouse released ';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(tested with http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ on IE9, Firefox and Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general terms, for debugging, step through it with a debugger / dom inspector. Look at the CSS being applied. Look at which CSS rules win the cascade. Look at which CSS rules are deleted as invalid.

The `left` and `top` properties accept lengths not numbers. You haven't put any units on the values.

(In quirks mode, some browsers think that `99` means *99 pixels* when it doesn't mean anything).

Comment: The solution, a change in onmousemove:
    img.style.left = ((window.event ? window.event.x: event.clientX) - img.mouseX) + "px";
    img.style.top = ((window.event ? window.event.y: event.clientY) - img.mouseY) + "px";